# Plot each individual community with iGraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have generated a community network using iGraph and qGraph to determine the relatedness between individual's genetic codes above a threshold edge value. To further analyze this data, I used cluster_walktrap and then graphed this along with the network. I am wondering if there is a way label the individual communities, as well as plot a single community from the batch. I can provide extra details if need be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something using `components`, e.g.,

```
sapply(components(g), plot)
```